# rootViewController magic

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm digging in PlainNote app [source code](https://github.com/vkoser/PlainNote/blob/master/Classes/PlainNoteAppDelegate.m). I notice that there is no instance of rootviewcontroller in appdelegate file. There is only navigationController added to window, but somehow the rootViewController is loaded also.

How this is achieved ?

Comment: The rootViewController is probably loaded trough the navigation controller. Did you take a look at the nibs too? It might help you discover how it's done

Comment: Yes, Bogdan's got it. In the .xib, see if there are any instantiated objects, right click on them and see what instance variables they're bound to.

Answer (score 1):

Check in the MainWindow.xib. That's actually pretty standard way - the XCode Application templates do it too.